# What is the point of adding "IP domain.tld" to the ( /etc/hosts ) file if the server is not gonna be used as a mail server?

Tags: linux, apache, dns, centos, hosts

For a domain name to work.. it's DNS servers simply need to point it to the correct IP.

once the domain tries to connect to the IP

the server simply uses the APACHE configuration to determine what to do with the domain
based on what is in the

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
</VirtualHost>
```

for the `ServerName`, `ServerAlias` etc.

so if i decide not to set up a mail server, then i never have to bother adding

```
IP domain.tld
```

to the `/etc/hosts` file ?

i suppose `/etc/hosts` file only needs a `IP domain.tld` if there is a mail server setup?

Comment: you use the host file to add any IP of the servers that your linux box will interact with

Answer (score 2):

/etc/hosts file is an alternative to DNS host name resolution.  It has nothing specifically to do with mail servers.  But, to use a mail server it has to be found on the network.

/etc/hosts is a local lookup file that computer uses as specified in /etc/nsswitch.conf.

DNS is a network service provided for each domain.  For example, BIND.  Domain zone files are configured and hosted on the domains primary DNS servers.

You can configure domain searches in /etc/resolv.conf.